# On which day goddess Parvati was born?

Tags: avatars, devi, parvati, birth

It is said that Devi Annapurna [was born on](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/37056/what-is-the-exact-story-of-the-origin-of-goddess-annapurna) Akshaya Tritiya.

Was Devi Parvati born on Akshay tritiya?

When was goddess Parvati born?

Answer (score 2):

**No. Goddess Parvati was not born on Akshaya Tritiya**, which is [celebrated on](https://www.drikpanchang.com/hindu-festivals/akshaya-tritiya/akshaya-tritiya.html) the third day of the bright fortnight of the Vaishakha month.

However, as per the Shiva Purana,

**Devi Parvati was born on the midnight of the ninth day of Chaitra Month.**

<sup>*The text, according to me, seems unclear on whether it was Shukla Paksha (Bright-fortnight) or Krishna Paksha (Dark-Fortnight).*</sup>

This is found in the Shiva Purana 2.3.6

> [Chapter 6](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226070.html), Rudra-saṃhitā (3): Pārvatī-khaṇḍa, Shiva Purāṇa
>
> तस्मिन्नवसरे देवी पूर्वशक्तिश्शिवा सती । आविर्बभूव पुरतो मेनाया
> निजरूपतः ॥ ३१ ॥
>
> > 31. At that time Śivā, Satī of perfect power formerly appeared in front of Menā in her real form.
>
> ---
>
> वसंतर्तौ मधौ मासे नवम्यां मृगधिष्ण्यके । अर्द्धरात्रे समुत्पन्ना गंगेव
> शशिमण्डलात् ॥ ३२ ॥
>
> > 32. **She was born at midnight when the constellation Mṛgaśiras was in conjunction with the moon on the ninth day in the month of Madhu
> >     (March-April) in the spring season like the Gaṅgā from the moon’s
> >     sphere.**
>
> ---
>
> समये तत्स्वरूपेण मेनका जठराच्छिवा । समुद्भूय समुत्पन्ना सा लक्ष्मीरिव
> सागरात् ॥ ३३ ॥
>
> > 33. Coming out of the belly of Menā at the proper time in her real form, she resembled Lakṣmī coming out of the ocean.
>
> ---
>
> ततस्तस्यां तु जातायां प्रसन्नोऽभूत्तदा भवः । अनुकूलो ववौ वायुर्गम्भीरो
> गंधयुक्शुभः ॥ ३४ ॥
>
> > 34. When she was born, Śiva was glad. A slow, fragrant and auspicious wind blew favourably.
>
> ---
>
> बभूव पुष्पवृष्टिश्च तोयवृष्टि पुरस्सरम् । जज्वलुश्चाग्नयः शान्ता
> जगर्जुश्च तदा घनाः ॥ ३५ ॥
>
> > 35. Along with the rain there was a shower of flowers. Fires calmly glowed and the clouds rumbled.
>
> ......
>
> English Translation by J.L. Shastri

<sup>*Access the alternate Hindi Translation by Gita Press Gorakhpur [from here](https://archive.org/details/SHIVPURANHINDI/page/n215/mode/1up?view=theater), and the English Translation from the Hinduscriptures website [from here](http://hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/siva-mahapurana/vol-i/chapter-101/topic-1)*</sup>

---

## To conclude -

- **So, goddess Parvati was born on the Ninth day of Chaitra Month, under the Mṛgaśiras Nakṣatra.**

  - (*it's not clear if the ninth day is from shukla paksha or krishna paksha*)

- Interestingly, if it's somehow proved that her birth was on the Shukla Paksha of the Chaitra Month, then that makes it coincide with the Rama Navami, and also the ninth day of the Chaitra Navaratri, the day of goddess Siddhidatri.