# What is the exact story of the origin of goddess Annapurna?

Tags: shiva, parvati, kashi

Which scripture talks about goddess parvati taking the form of Annapurna? Did she take this form on the auspicious day of Akshay tritiya? Why did Lord Shiva beg in front of her? I want to know the story behind this.

Answer (score 1):

One day, Shiva and Parvati got into an argument about the importance of Prakriti, which Shiva denied, stressing on superiority of Purush (male) over Prakriti (Mother Nature). Enraged, Parvati abandoned him and disappeared.With Parvati's disappearance, the world was deprived of food and there occurred a famine. When Shiva's followers started begging him for food, Shiva took a begging bowl and went from door to door begging for food. But no one had anything to offer, for those whom Shiva begged from themselves were affected. Shiva and his followers came to know that on earth, there is only one kitchen in the city of Kashi where food is still available. Shiva went to Kashi to beg for food, but to his surprise, the kitchen was owned by none other than his wife Parvati, but in a different form. She wore celestial purple and brown garments and was lightly adorned with ornaments, and she was seated on a throne, serving and distributed food to starving Gods and hungry inhabitants of earth, one after another. She also offered food to her sons Kartikeya and Ganesh as well. This beautiful form of Parvati was none other than Goddess Annapurna Devi, she who is full and complete. Annapurna offered her food as alms to Shiva and made Him realise that as Brahman, Shiva might have outgrown hunger; but his followers haven't.[6] There is another legend which says Trimurti once had heated argument who among them is greatest each saying his achievements when Mahadevi heard their argument she decided to teach them a lesson and disappeared causing severe faminine as a result no yajnas were done and devas started grewing weak and asked Trimurti for food then Lord Vishnu said to Lord Shiva " O Mahadev it was true what you said after Devi disappeared universe became weak ; I heard a lady in Kashi started donating food for people." At once Lord Shiva understood that the lady was none other than jagdamba and went to Kashi in disguise of mendicant and begged food from Devi for devas. Devi happy that Devas had learnt their lesson said to Mahadev " I shall reside here in Kashi in form of Annapurna."

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annapurna_(goddess)#Legend

Comment: Thanks for the interesting account. May I know where this story is found?